# Communicate between .NET desktop applications over local network

Tags: c#, wcf

I need simple way of communication between 2 desktop application over local network. Client application have to call server and trigger command execution on server desktop. RPC is the old way of doing that. Looks like WCF is new way.

- If WCF, does it require IIS on the computer that is running server application?
- Where I can find WCF sample code to follow?

Comment: WCF is just a decorator. It will still implement RPC style services. It does support REST however Microsoft has the designated WebAPI framework for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two Windows applications, you're probably going to want a self-hosted WCF service using Net TCP binding.

Self-hosted means the service is contained in your application (could be a desktop app or Windows service) - no IIS required. Just about any kind of binding will work, but Net TCP binding is ideal for .NET applications that only talk to other .NET applications over a LAN.

Here's a [sample from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx) on self-hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You can host WCF in various ways  - IIS, windows service, console application.

So no, you do not need IIS installed unless you want to host it on IIS.

Here are some examples on how to do it

[Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx)